# Can scp be used non-interactively in cron without generating keys?

Tags: unix, cron, scp

I have a nightly database backup which I would like to scp to a remote server.  As near as I can tell scp cannot be invoked with a password in the command and instead you need to set up keys for the servers?

Per this: http://www.spaceprogram.com/knowledge/cron_scp.html

The remote box owner does not want me to set up the keys so what would you do to get the file from one box to the other via a cron job?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why does the remote owner not want you to set up keys?

The key is the same as a password, or even better because it's easier to track where it's used.  The right solution is, without a doubt, to generate a keypair and use that for unattended authentication.

Now, if you really need to use `scp` without public-key auth, you can do it either by using an `expect` library to enter the password into `scp`, or by using an `ssh` library instead of invoking the `scp` command externally.  Either way, you'll have to set up a wrapper that gets used by `cron` instead of calling `scp` directly.

Comment: I think it is a case of fear born of ignorance.  The response I got was "You can store the files here.  That is it.  We are not adding or changing anything." but the owner of said files wants them stored on this particular server.  I can just write a SFTP script in Perl.

Comment: Someone over there talked them down off the ledge.  Have got key based auth working from cron.  Thanks!